# Android Bitmap to Emgucv Image<>, NullReference Error

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android, emgucv

My program starts with a Base64 string which i turn into a byte array

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64);
```

then i turn the byte array into a Bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

then i try to use the Emgucv Image<> Bitmap constructor

```
image = new Image<Gray, byte>(bitmap);
```

but i get this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've debugged and can confirm that the bitmap is being created successfully and has a byte count, width, height but still gives me this error. Here's the full method I'm using to go from Base64 to Emgucv UMat.

```
 private async void SetBase64Pattern()
    {
        detection.Clear();
        foreach (Assets asset in lstAssets)
        {
            if (asset.Used == 1)
            {
                detection.Add(0);

                UMat imagePattern = new UMat();
                VectorOfKeyPoint keyPoint = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
                Mat desc = new Mat();
                Image<Gray, byte> image;

                string imageBase64 = asset.AssetImage; 
                imageBase64 = imageBase64.Split(',')[1];
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64);
#if __IOS__
                NSData data = NSData.FromArray(bytes);
                UIImage uiImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                image = new Image<Gray, byte>(uiImage);
#elif __ANDROID__
                //IImageSourceHandler handler = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
                //Bitmap bitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes)), Forms.Context);
                //image = new Image<Gray, byte>(bitmap);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                image = new Image<Gray, byte>(bitmap);
#endif

                imagePattern = image.ToUMat();

                featureDetector.DetectAndCompute(imagePattern, null, keyPoint, desc, false);

                triggers.Add(imagePattern);
                triggersKPS.Add(keyPoint);
                triggersDescs.Add(desc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for looking!

### EDIT

Just wanted to mention that the iOS code in fact works and that's what makes this all the more confusing on why the Android code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question.
The images were gif images before being encoded to Base64. After changing the gif to a jpeg before being encoded the process now works.